# ITunes 11 new User Interface

Tags: cocoa, user-interface, interface-builder, nssegmentedcontrol

Itunes 11 introduces a new UI-Element. It is an additional button row below the toolbar:

[image: button row]

One purpose of this new row is the replacement of NSSegmentedControls.

How is it called and how would I build it with the Xcode Interface-Builder or by code.

Comment: It would be nice to know why someone simply down-votes my question without explanation.

Comment: I am guessing people think you are just here to ask for code, which our community frowns upon. We help; we don't do your coding.

Comment: I must also add this is a custom control, so it doesn't really have a name. About building it, you would probably have to write the code to draw it manually.